# The Piece in the Corner of my Jigsaw Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, jigsaw-puzzle

Don't know about you, but I personally enjoy relaxing at home, listening to good music and solving puzzles. Yesterday I was trying to finish one of my numerous jigsaws, when ended up with three corner pieces, all of which could fit perfectly the frame. Can you help me figure out which is the correct piece that completes the puzzle?

[image]

*P.S. I guess that's not hard/puzzly enough for PSE, but I think the picture ended up nice and wanted to share.*

*P.S.S. I did not draw the picture myself.*

Comment: Your words imply that this is not your puzzle, but your profile suggests otherwise... Please [be clear with your affiliation](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux) (or lack there of).

Comment: @Alconja The puzzle is mine, I sketched it, but asked another person to draw it. If the fourth piece with the link is an issue, I can remove it and leave just three.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan you have to remove **puzzleprime.com** from pic.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan ...to be honest, I don't really know if it is an issue or not. I was under the impression that others had been reprimanded for "self promotion" in the past, but the meta link I commented kind of implies otherwise (or rather it implies that *undisclosed* self promotion is a problem)...

Comment: @Alconja, Niranj, I left just the first three pieces, to be on the safe side. However, if there is a watermark on someone's content and there is effort put into it, I believe it is more reasonable to stay. This puzzle is not a masterpiece and I do not care much, just saying in general.
P.S. My intention was not to make undisclosed self promotion, I just did not want to leave others with the impression that I am the artist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This puzzle describe the lyrics of our favorite song

> - "[House of the Rising Sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A-4VGfx5lU)" by Animals.

So final answer is

> second one (the first one depicts "The Eagles" and the third one depicts "The Rolling Stones").